# About critical points and vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry

How can I show that if $p$ is a critical point of a real-valued function $f$ then the function $H(X_p,Y_p)=X_p(Yf)$ depends only on Y_p$?

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is a critical point, then $W_pf=0$ for every tangent vector $W_p \in T_pM$.

Given $X_p,Y_p \in T_pM$, choose $X,Y$ vector fields extending both. Then
$$[X,Y]_p f=0,$$
from which follows that $$X_p(Yf)=Y_p(Xf).$$
By looking on the right side, we have that the formula doesn't depend on the extension $Y$, only on $Y_p$ (which I think is what you mean by "depends only on $Y_p$").